# How to add different static image to my static ListItems

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have a ListView example in which the image in listview is static coming from XML. I want to add different static images to static listitems. I am trying to add something like "items.add(new EntryItem("R.drawable.image", "Item 1", "This is item 1.1"));" How can i get such functionality ? Below is my working code :

SectionListExampleActivity.java

```
public class SectionListExampleActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 1", "This is item 1.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 2", "This is item 1.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 3", "This is item 1.3"));
       //"items.add(new EntryItem("R.drawable.image", "Item 1", "This is item 1.1"));"  //Is this possible ? 


        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 4", "This is item 2.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 5", "This is item 2.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 6", "This is item 2.3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 7", "This is item 2.4"));

        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 8", "This is item 3.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 9", "This is item 3.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 10", "This is item 3.3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 11", "This is item 3.4"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 12", "This is item 3.5"));

        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        if(!items.get(position).isSection()){

            EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);

            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.title , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```

EntryAdapter.java

```
public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public EntryAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context,0, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final Item i = items.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
            if(i.isSection()){
                SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

                v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);

                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            }else{
                EntryItem ei = (EntryItem)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
                final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);

                if (title != null) 
                    title.setText(ei.title);
                if(subtitle != null)
                    subtitle.setText(ei.subtitle);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

EntryItem.java

```
public class EntryItem implements Item{

    public final String title;
    public final String subtitle;

    public EntryItem(String title, String subtitle) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Item.java

```
public interface Item {

    public boolean isSection();

}
```

SectionItem.java

```
public class SectionItem implements Item{

    private final String title;

    public SectionItem(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

list_item_entry.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_section.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
        layout="@android:layout/preference_category" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate array of drawable items like this:

```
int[] img = { R.drawable.first, R.drawable.second, R.drawable.third,
        R.drawable.fourth};
```

And add them in list in a loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess that will be difficult part. Can i do something like which i am trying to do ? Will that possible ? How ?

Comment: @user45678 You can check in if...else for current position in array, and code accordingly. But I would not suggest doing that. That will not be optimized solution :)

Comment: Thanks Mystic Magic. I guess i will have to add Bitmap class for that ? I am new to it. if you don't mind can you show me an example to do that ? That will be really helpful...Much regards

Comment: @user45678 Check [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-5-optimized-custom-listview/) tutorial and [this](http://javatyro.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-listview-example.html), too.

Comment: Thanks Mystic Magic. I tried it but for my case it won't work because i am saving state of my listitems into shared preference many times and redrawing adapter many times. Hence only possible case will be to put along with items and saving it in shared preference every time and retrieve back.